# Comparing two datetime fields in a table and displaying a record in another table based on the result

Tags: mysql, sql, database, datetime

I am trying to compare the to datetime fields in my `loan` table so if the difference between the dates is bigger then 31 days I can get the names from the `borrowers` table of the borrowers, who delayed the return of their book. I am not allowed to use triggers or stored procedures for the task, so I am aiming to do it in another way, but I don't even know where to start.
I'd appreciate any tips on how to do that.

Here is the part of my database that is used for the task.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sentence should do the work:

```
SELECT
    borrower.idBorrowerPK,
    borrower.name
FROM
    loan
    left join borrower
        on load.Borrower_idBorrowerPK = borrower.idBorrowerPK
WHERE
    DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), loan.dateBorrowed) >= 31
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you should be able to join the loan table and borrower table and use a WHERE clause. Try this:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM borrower B
JOIN loan L 
ON L.Borrower_idBorrowerPK=B.idBorrowerPK
where datediff(L.dateReturned,L.dateBorrowed)>31
```